# Suggestions for fonts in classicthesis.sty

Tags: fonts, margins, classicthesis, kpfonts

I found these suggestions for fonts in classicthesis.sty. What are they for kpfonts? Does `Palatino     10pt: 288--312pt | 609--657pt` mean that `\textwidth` must be between  `288 and 312pt` and `\textheight` must be between `609 and 657pt`?

```
% Here are some suggestions for the text widths and heights:
% Palatino  10pt: 288--312pt | 609--657pt
% Palatino  11pt: 312--336pt | 657--705pt
% Palatino  12pt: 360--384pt | 768pt
% Minion      10pt: 264--288pt | 561--609pt
% Minion      11pt: 288--312pt | 609--657pt
% Minion      12pt: 336pt      | 672pt
% Libertine 10pt:
% Libertine 11pt:
% Libertine 12pt:
% kpfonts 10pt:
% kpfonts 11pt:
% kpfonts 12pt:
```

Comment: I think `kpfonts` were based originally on `palatino`, so you are probably fine with those settings.  Off-hand, I'd say that `kpfonts` are wider than `Minion Pro` and `Libertine`, but you're probably better testing it for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the following test, KP Fonts are similar in size to

```
Palatino:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums,largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}%

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand{\testlen}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\mylen}{\testlen}
KP Fonts: \the\mylen
\typeout{KP Fonts: \the\mylen}

\begingroup
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
\settowidth{\mylen}{\testlen}
Palatino: \the\mylen
\typeout{Palatino: \the\mylen}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
KP Fonts: 159.05984pt
Palatino: 159.85011pt
```

So I'd use the same settings for KP Fonts as for Palatino.